# Python: Does 'kron' create sparse matrix when I use ' from scipy.sparse import * '?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

For the code below, Mat is a array-type matrix,

```
a = kron(Mat,ones((8,1)))
b = a.flatten()
```

If I don't import scipy.sparse package, `a` is an **array-type matrix**, `b` can also be executed.
If I use 'from scipy.sparse import *', `a` is a **sparse-type matrix**, `b` **cannot** be exectued.
Can someone tell me why `kron` gives different results? 
And, whether flatten() can be applied to sparse-type matrix?

Comment: Use `from scipy import sparse` and `sparse.kron ...` or `np.kron ...` so there isn't confusion.  You can also print `a`to tell whether its dense or sparse.

Comment: Thank you! @hpaulj , do you mean `kron` exist both in package`scipy.sparse`' and `numpy`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`from module import *` is generally considered bad form in application code, for the reason you're seeing - it makes it very hard to tell which modules functions are coming from, especially if you do this for more than one module

Right now, you have:

```
from numpy import *
# from scipy.sparse import *
a = kron(Mat,ones((8,1)))
b = a.flatten()
```

Uncommenting the second line might affect where `ones` and `kron` comes from. But unless you look up whether sparse redefines these, you won't know. Better to write it like this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
a = np.kron(Mat, np.ones((8,1)))
b = a.flatten()
```

And then you can swap `np` for `sparse` where you want to use the sparse version, and the reader will immediately know which one you're using. And you'll get an error if you try to use a sparse version when in fact there isn't one.